# Dynamic_Cast vector elements

Tags: c++, iterator, dynamic-cast

I'm trying to create a new type vector containing elements from a base class. What I did is a dynamic_cast of the base class vector elements to the derived type in order to apply some methods I added in the derived class.

This is what I approximately did:

```
std::vector<BaseClass *> A;
std::vector<DerivedClass *> B;
DerivedClass *m = new DerivedClass;
std::vector<BaseClass *>::const_iterator iterator = A.begin();
AMD_STD::vector<BaseClass *>::const_iterator iteratorEnd = A.end()

for(; iterator!= iteratorEnd; ++iterator)
{
 m = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass *>(*iterator); 
 B.push_back(m);
}
 B->MyMethod();
```

The problem is that I'm having a NULL pointer when I try to apply the method and it's generating execution errors.
I think the problem is due to a dynamic_cast fail. Could Anyone help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a minimal code that actually reproduces the issue so we can see it. Hard to tell from the snippet you've posted - conceptually there is nothing wrong with it (in general - it won't compile).

Comment: Can you post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we can run and displays your issue? `B->MyMethod()` won't compile and you never populate `A`.

Comment: Well, `dynamic_cast` is a code smell. You probably should rethink your design.

Comment: Is this entire code? Seems incorrect. A does not have any elements. Also line the memory allocation done for m(`DerivedClass *m = new DerivedClass;`) seems useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(*iterator)` fails and returns `nullptr` when `*iterator` is not `nullptr`, then you've added an element to the vector that *is* of type `BaseClass*`, but *is not* of type `DerivedClass*`. Simple as that.

You haven't showed any code where you add vector elements though and you explicitly said "This is what I approximately did", which leaves the arena open for other truths.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously when `B` is a `vector`,  `B->MyMethod();` won't compile, but assuming you're trying to iterate over `B` later and invoke `MyMethod` on each pointer therein, your problem will be the `nullptr`s you've pushed into the `vector` `B`.  To avoid putting them in there, only push when they're not null:

```
for( ; iterator!= iteratorEnd; ++iterator)
     if (m = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass *>(*iterator))
         B.push_back(m);
```

---

Separately, I recommend localising variable lifetimes to the smallest possible scope of use and using C++11 notation:

```
for (auto& base_ptr : B)
     if (DerivedClass* p = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass *>(base_ptr))
         B.push_back(p);
```

Comment: "Brevity is wit" is not an universal constant. For the maintainer's sake, being more explicit is better. `if((m = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass *>(*iterator)) != nullptr)`. Plus, I'm sure some compilers would give you a warning for parenthesized assignment in a condition.

Comment: I think Tony's code is idiomatic, pretty much anyone who has used `dynamic_cast` before will see what it's doing.

Comment: @Medinoc: I disagree that comparing with `nullptr` is useful - implicit conversions of pointers and integers to `true`/`false` values is intuitive and worth learning early as a C++ programmer; true about some compilers giving warnings... and a damned pain because C++ doesn't let you create an `if`-scoped variable (as I do in the second code snippet) if you add extra parentheses.  I'd recommend disabling that particular warning (perhaps enabling occasionally and grepping out non-problematic cases).

Comment: I won't argue about the implicit true/falseness in an assignment-free test, but when the test contains an assignment it's best to go for explicitness rather than take any chances.

Comment: @Medinoc: that's not even possible for the localised form `if (DerivedClass* p = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass *>(base_ptr))` - adding a comparison to `nullptr` can only yield a `bool` before assignment which prevents proper assignment to the pointer.  And I don't consider explicitness to be less risky - the difference between `(a = b) != nullptr` and `(a = b) == nullptr` is relatively subtle; by only using the `== nullptr` when it makes a difference (inverting the boolean sense), it highlights the significance far better.  We'll have to agree to disagree...